# R言語　if_elseの挙動について

Tags: r

以下のデータフレーム ex　があります。

> ex
>       name score test rank
>   1   john    80    0    4
>   2   taro    60    0    3
>   3  betty    70   NA    2
>   4 hanako    50    0    1

testがNAのとき、rankもNAにしたいとき

> mutate(ex,rank = if_else(test == 0,true = rank,false = NA))

と入力するとエラーが出る一方、

> mutate(ex,rank = if_else(test == 0,true = rank,false = 0))

と入力すると望んだ結果が得られます。
どうしてこのようなことになるのか、教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::if_else()` は、引数`true`と `false`に与える型が同じでなければいけません。
今回はrank列が実数なので、 `NA`の中でも実数を指定する`NA_real_` を与える必要があります。

`mutate(ex, rank = if_else(test == 0, true = rank, false = NA_real_))`

また、質問の

> testがNAのとき、rankもNAにしたいとき

では下記のようにするのが良いと思います。

```
mutate(ex, rank = if_else(is.na(test), true = NA_real_, false = rank))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   name   score  test  rank
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 john      80     0     4
#> 2 taro      60     0     3
#> 3 betty     70    NA    NA
#> 4 hanako    50     0     1
```